# Parsing CSV file rows for SpreadSheets upload with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, parsing, google-sheets

I'm trying to send leads from CSV to Google Sheets with AJAX like
[this method](https://blog.aulaformativa.com/formularios-con-php-y-google-sheets/)
for send form leads to Google Sheets.

I got it with this code in Gogole App Script but i need this in local to do more actions as delete csv file on finish.

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {

  var csvUrl = "http://URL/csv/data.csv";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = range.getLastRow();

  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

This is an example of my data.csv

```
"4","7","22300","johndoe@example.com","John","Doe","Company SL","666123456","519780151","","","","Instagram"
"6","10","08028","johnsmith@example.com","John","Smith","Company2 SL","666456789","519780151","","","","Facebook"
```

And this is my AJAX script:

```
  <script>
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });//disable cache

    $.ajax({
        url: 'csv/data.csv',
        dataType: 'text',
      }).done(successFunction);

    function successFunction(data) {
      var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
      for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {

      var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split(',');
        document.querySelector("#leads-csv").innerHTML += rowCells+"<br/>";

        //alert(rowCells);

        const sheetsURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/exec'
      const sheets = document.forms['form-csv'] //evento de formulario


            sheets.addEventListener('submit', e => {
                e.preventDefault()

                alert("Se va a insertar en Google Sheets");//once by row

                fetch(sheetsURL, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: new FormData(sheets) //Failed to construct FormData!!
                    })
                    .then(response => console.log('Datos guardados en Google Sheets', response))
                    .catch(error => console.error('¡Error, revisa el código superior!', error.message))
            });
      }
    }
    </script>
```

I have the problem when i trying to create the FormData with CSV rows

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `the problem` of `I have the problem when i trying to create the FormData with CSV rows`?

Comment: Could you explain which is the flow of your code? To which server/application are you making the requests? Which is the error you're getting?

Comment: The Chrome console show me "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData':parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'" on the line "body: new FormData(sheets)".

Anyway I've changed the focus to use server side tools. Finally i used Guzzle PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used Guzzle PHP, submitting async forms is much easier than cheating with javascript. Here the little snippet of victory:

```
    $file = fopen("csv/datos.csv", "r");

    if($file) {

    //If file exists, start read
    while(! feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);

    //Convert complete line to single fields  
    $singleLine = explode(",",$line);  

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        //CSV fields to Google Sheets fields
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/URL/exec', [
                'form_params' => [
                'nombreDeVariable2' => $singleLine[0],
                'nombreDeVariable3' => $singleLine[1],
                'Zip' => $singleLine[2],
                'email' => $singleLine[3],
                'first_name' => $singleLine[4],
                'last_name' => $singleLine[5],
                'company' => $singleLine[6],
                'phone' => $singleLine[7],
                'elqSiteId' => $singleLine[8],
                'comentarios' => $singleLine[9],
                'gdpr_legitimate_interest' => $singleLine[10],
                'retURL' => $singleLine[11],
                'web' => $singleLine[12],
            ]
        ]);
```

For post to JSON API y only changed "form_params" for "json", adding API end point and this lines after:

```
$response = $client->post("/end-point", $options);
echo $response->getBody();
```